using redux in my react project, i save the token gotten from the user and trying to use it in other components/
I am using redux in a project, the issue is that am saving a token gotten from  login of a user, but when i try to use it a component it returns null.
i used console.log to verify that it saving in the redux store but when using consolelog to check if am extracting it correctly it returns null.
this my redux store
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import session_slice from "./slices/session_slice";
import term_slice from "./slices/term_slice";
import login_slice from "./slices/login_slice";
import tenant_slice from "./slices/tenant_slice";


export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    session: session_slice,
    term: term_slice,
    login: login_slice,
    tenant: tenant_slice,
  }
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

this part is where am trying to check it in a component but it returns null
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Real = () => {
  const token = useSelector(state => state.login.token);

  // Use the token for operations here
  console.log("Token in component:", token);

  return <div>My Component</div>;
}

export default Real

this is my loginsplice where i save the user token and data gotten from my api.
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import login from '../../api/admin/login';

export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk('login/loginUser', async ({ email, password }, { rejectWithValue }) => {
  try {
    const data = await login(email, password);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    return rejectWithValue(error.message); // Capture and return the error message
  }
});

const loginSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'login',
  initialState: {
    user: null,
    token: null, // Add token to initial state
    status: 'idle',
    error: null
  },
  reducers: {
    logout: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
      state.token = null; // Clear the token on logout
    }
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(loginUser.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
        state.error = null; // Clear previous errors
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'succeeded';
        state.user = action.payload.data;
        console.log(action.payload.data)
        state.token = action.payload.data.token; // Store the token
        console.log(action.payload.data.token)
        state.error = null; // Clear previous errors
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'failed';
        state.error = action.payload; // Capture error message
      });
  }
});

export const { logout } = loginSlice.actions;
export default loginSlice.reducer;
 


After you get the token and store it into the Redux store... (you have actually verified the store update via the Redux-devtools, right?)... what exactly are you doing before, and up to, checking the selected state in that Real component? In other words, what are your exact reproduction steps to produce the issue. Note that this may mean you also need to provide a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, i.e. the code that updates the state, the code that reads it, and anything between the two.

use local storage to store token
localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));


Please explain in some detail what the issue is and how this resolves it.

Actually according to your problem you need to check redux store value after update it . it able to use redux dev tools for that one . but the thing is if page refresh  your token will be loss and user will able to login again . so prevent that one you need to use local storage for store token
